# Deleted all permissions on google cloud storage

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gsutil, google-iam

I deleted all the permissions on the google cloud storage console. Now I am unable to delete bucket contents or add permission to a user, even using gsutil.

I want to delete the bucket, how do I do that.

Answer (score 1):

I went to IAM admin and added the necessary permission to the project group (in my case champion-hosting).

Although this works, I wonder why google would allow a logged in user to delete his own permissions and locking himself out.